# Sorting by age a list class in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, class, sorting

I'm a beginner and I want to create an implementation that prints 
all the user information to the console, ordered by age. I've tried to use Linq but without success.
This is the code base:

```
class User
{
    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public int age;
}

interface UsersConsumer { public void consume(List<Users> collection); }
```

This is what I tried to do into the interface:

```
List<User> SortedUserList = 
    collection.OrderByDescending(collection => collection.age).ToList();
```

Comment: whats the error? you have an interface so I assume you had another class implementing the interface and thats where you put the code snippet you have?

Comment: You named the parameter of the lambda expression `collection`, although there is already a variable called `collection` (the list itself). Have you tried `collection.OrderByDescending(c => c.age).ToList();`? What error do you get?

Comment: yes sorry, the error is "A local variable named `collection' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a 
different meaning to `collection', which is already used in a `parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a different variable name inside your lambda expression like:

```
List<User> SortedUserList = collection.OrderByDescending(row => row.age).ToList();
```

Otherwise you will end up with an error like:

> A local variable named 'collection' cannot be declared in this scope
>   because it would give a different meaning to 'collection', which is
>   already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

EDIT: Just noticed one thing:

> This is what I tried to do into the interface:

You can't have implementation in your interface. Interface is more of a contract, You have to implement your interface in a class and then put the implementation like:

```
public class SomeClass : UsersConsumer 
{
    public void consume(List<User> collection)
    {
        List<User> SortedUserList = collection.OrderByDescending(row => row.age).ToList();
    }
}
```

Make sure, that you follow [.Net naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can't sort because program don't know HOW to sort it. Just write
`class User : IComparable<User>`
now program know that User can be compared with another User. Now write HOW:

`public int CompareTo(User u)
        {
            return age.CompareTo(u.age);
        }`

Now program knows, that you can sort Users by their age. So you can sort them `collection.Sort()` and write them :-)